# Bootstrap Navbar Logo pixelated on phone

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am creating a website with bootstrap, I've been trying to do the navbar and everything works perfectly except on my mobile phone because the logo gets blurry or pixelated, I am not sure if its getting resized automatically but even if I use an smaller version of the logo it still looks blurry.

Like this: [Small Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maPFg.jpg), [Big Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihccr.jpg)

It also sticks to the bottom of the navbar ignoring any padding/margin

I am using a pull-left class beacuse it seems to work better for images than navbar-brand.

**html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="images/logonavbar.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">LOG IN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TOURNAMENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

**css**

```
.pull-left {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

It also works perfectly on my mini iPad screen and on any browser (even when scaling down the window)

This is my website:  [Windfury.net](http://windfury.net)

Comment: in which phone  Logo is pixelated?

Comment: I've only tried with a Moto G phone, have you tried with another device?

Comment: Website doesn't exist?

Comment: add (style="transform: translate3d(0,0,0);") in the img tag to see if it helps. That will put it on the hardware graphics layer. usually clears images that are blured

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a higher resolution image and set its width/height to size you want it to end up showing.

This happens because your phone has more pixels than your desktop screen. So to compensate, your phone stretches the pixels to make it fill the same amount of space on screen. Therefore you end up with a blurred images as 1 pixel of the image != 1 pixel on you phone screen, it's usually a lot more, depending on the device.

A good practice to follow is to have one image for example 100x200 px, then have another 200 x 400px. Then use media queries to scale the larger images down to 100 x 200px for mobile or high resolution devices.

That would require the use of background images however. If you want to just use an image tag, you could just use the single larger image and scale it down normally using css `width: 100px; height: 200px` - the only drawback is that non high resolution devices will have to download an image bigger than necessary.

the following example shows off what I'm talking about, albeit with more than the 2 to 1 ratio, considering the image in the example is quite small and jsfiddle isn't great on a mobile device.

https://jsfiddle.net/s15swcn0/2/

Comment: You are right, it's fixed after adding an image two times bigger and then resizing on the img tag. I will try to fix it with media queries later. 

Thank you so much for your help!